# In which dialects is "knowed" the past tense of know?

Tags: etymology, dialects, conjugation, irregular-verbs

In some folk songs, such as Woody Guthrie's "Hard Traveling" and Townes Van Zandt's "Poncho and Lefty," the word "knowed" is used as the past tense of "know."

To what extent and in which dialects has "knowed" actually been used? I find it interesting because common irregulars tend to be well conserved over time (like go→went, is→was, etc), so I'm wondering under what conditions "knowed" would have, uh, arised.

Comment: I've seen this used for Appalachian and "hillbilly" dialects, but I don't know if it's real or fake.

Comment: Oh, arised good. Yes, I'd say rural, minimal education, nothing past the little red schoolhouse.

Comment: It's the regular past tense of _know_, which is usually irregular. But these choices vary, like the past tense of _dive_, which is regular some places and irregular others. There isn't one single "dialect" where all the oddities one notices in others' speech come from. There are millions of idiolects, each unique, occasionally coalescing around social groups; but social groups are fickle and changeable.

Comment: Sure, but the fact that the word is extremely uncommon (try googling for organic usage), combined with the fact that it seems to pop up in folk music and is uttered by the Sheriff in "No Country For Old Men" suggests that its usage is more common in rural American speech. I'm trying to characterize that more precisely—fickle and changeable though social groups may be.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in whether it may be an affectation invented by people trying to sound "country" by speaking in a less normative way to convey lack of education. I'm not saying that is so, but all actual usages I know of involve, I think, some performative country-ness. I dunno.

Comment: It's present in speech, and not that uncommon. Google and other language databases cover **printed** sources, not spoken language, and not socioeconomic speech groups. Plus language in songs is consciously rural and archaic, often incorrectly so -- people imitate how they think other people talk, but they don't bother to ask the people who they think talk that way first.

Comment: Some progress on this is possible by using ngram, which at least gives some clues. For example, https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Hearings/_vra2oI0an0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22knowed%22&pg=PA4356&printsec=frontcover suggests the usage may be found in Louisiana. But this would be a huge job and would still miss non-written usage, leaving the answer open to a lot of opinion unless someone here has done a substantial academic study on dialect distribution.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler commented:

> It's the regular past tense of *know*, which is usually irregular. But these choices vary, like the past tense of *dive,* which is regular some places and irregular others. There isn't one single "dialect" where all the oddities one notices in others' speech come from. There are millions of idiolects, each unique, occasionally coalescing around social groups; but social groups are fickle and changeable.

As well as a follow up in comment:

> It's present in speech, and not that uncommon. Google and other language databases cover **printed** sources, not spoken language, and not socioeconomic speech groups. Plus language in songs is consciously rural and archaic, often incorrectly so -- people imitate how they think other people talk, but they don't bother to ask the people who they think talk that way first. –
> John Lawler
> May 18, 2022 at 3:04

Comment: All the above is true but it must also be said there is a class component to this. Those who are educated would not generally use it. So, a sheriff in a small southern town would not use it but the guy he arrests for drunk and disorderly conduct might.

Comment: @Lambie I've said this before, but: please cite your sources for these sorts of sociolinguistic facts. You need to provide evidence for the claim that there are differences by social class and education level, since one's own intuitions on such matters can be unreliable.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with that. Most grammar/semantic issues are about what people internalize so even those studying these phenomena would have to locate them in certain **speech** communities. You don't learn these forms at school: you learn them from the speech communities  (family, care givers) in which you grew up. And my comment is not out of keeping with what the dear departed John Lawler said in this posted answer.

Comment: @Lambie The issue is that your personal observations of your community may not generalize very well. The way that "educated" and "less educated" people talk varies immensely by region, race, age, etc. and the language itself changes over time. (One example: negative concord, as in "I didn't say nothing," has historically been seen as uneducated, but I'm pretty sure this is no longer the case; a lot of very well-educated people I know use it in certain restricted contexts.)

Comment: I'm not talking about my community. As an actual linguist, I think I am qualified enough to judge the difference between educated and uneducated (unschooled) speaking forms. And it isn't just a matter of a single usage (double negative), it's a question of discourse (not in the sense of field or subject matter) and collocations. Arlo Guthrie is known for his "down home speech usage". For example. And most of these references would be seeking "confirmation" from others like me. Yeah, I use ain't too but know when I am using it. Beyond that, whatever **anybody at all says is fine**.

Comment: I never confuse judgment of the speech with identifying it. If I say something is unschooled or non-standard, I am not judging those speakers to be less worthy than me. Someone who uses "knowed" is also likely to use "I seen him yesterday" or "I done it good, huh?"

Comment: John Lawler says: "**It's** the regular past tense of know, which is usually irregular". But *he is not referring to knowed there*. The regular past tense of know is knew...Even he would agree, looking down from heaven. :) Also, it would be good to have a link there.

Comment: And I am not sure at all that comes from John Lawler anyway. Take a look at that sentence here: https://copyprogramming.com/howto/thats-that-was-one-of-the-worst-experiences-duplicate livresque may have got this wrong.

Comment: @livresque Can you cite the places where these quotes were found?

Comment: I think this whole thing may be falsely attributed to JL. Did you see the link I give above? That is the only hit I could find for this and it does not come from Lawler.

Comment: @Lambie It's in the comments on the question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/589033/in-which-dialects-is-knowed-the-past-tense-of-know/611902?noredirect=1#comment1479226_589033

Comment: Well, the link should be in the answer.  Anyway, he says it's that because people say it. Not very meaningful, in this case.